# Styling radio button above the label

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm using CSS sprites to add some custom background Radios. I need 2 styles (radio on left of label and radio on top of label).

I have tried inline-block and margin:auto (inline-styles in HTML) on my span to move the radio above but now the background is now in 00 position.

How can I style my radio so that it is above the label and centered?

```css
.my-radio-class {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-radio-class+span {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG6IV.gif');
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: -22px;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-radio-class:checked+span {
  background-position: -22px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="mys-radio-1" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
    <span></span>
    <label for="mys-radio-1">Small</label>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="pt-5">Above</h3>
<br />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="mys-radio-2" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
    <span style="display:inline-block: margin:auto;"></span>
    <label for="mys-radio-2">Small - Need Radio Above</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sprite
[image]

Comment: what you meant by above the label? ..please explore it ...then i will try to solve that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this one.
I have put the `input` and `span` elements into `label` element. And i have aligned the elements with `dislpay:flex`.

```css
.my-radio-class {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-radio-class+span {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG6IV.gif');
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-radio-class:checked+span {
  background-position: -22px 0;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
}

label.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

label.center span {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">

    <label for="mys-radio-1">
      <input id="mys-radio-1" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
      <span></span>
      Small</label>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="pt-5">Above</h3>
<br />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">

    <label for="mys-radio-2" class="center">
      <input id="mys-radio-2" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
      <span></span>
      Small - Need Radio Above</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this as the correct answer as this was the closest to what I needed. This also enabled me to wrap the radio in the label giving me the ability to make the whole area selectable. Using flexbox was better without adding and hacking at margins

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:block` on the span you want to move below. You will have to play around with `margin-left` and `margin-top` to move its position.

To give you an idea:

```css
.my-radio-class {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mys-radio-2+span{
  display: block;
  margin-left: 11px;
  margin-top:-30px;
}

.my-radio-class+span {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG6IV.gif');
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: -22px;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-radio-class:checked+span {
  background-position: -22px 0;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="pt-5">Left</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="mys-radio-1" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
    <span></span>
    <label for="mys-radio-1">Small</label>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="pt-5">Above</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="mys-radio-2" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
    <span style="display:inline-block: margin:auto;"></span>
    <label for="mys-radio-2">Small</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add some css code to your div tag

> .center {  display:flex;  justify-content:center;  }

to make it center

```css
.my-radio-class {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-radio-class+span {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG6IV.gif');
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: -22px;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.my-radio-class:checked+span {
  background-position: -22px 0;
}

.center {
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="mys-radio-1" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
    <span></span>
    <label for="mys-radio-1">Small</label>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 class="pt-5">Above</h3>
<br />
<div class="row center">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="mys-radio-2" class="my-radio-class" type="radio" name="my-group">
    <span style="display:inline-block: margin:auto;"></span>
    <label for="mys-radio-2">Small - Need Radio Above</label>
  </div>
</div>
```